# How to solve this error ? failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM requires either one or three arguments

Tags: docker

```sh
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine AS build-step
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN  npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the same Dockerfile on my PC, it worked fine! Can you send me more information about the code?
Thanks